# admin.StackedInline in the Django Template

Tags: python, django, backend

I am using Django.
I made a Menu class in models.py

```
class Menu(models.Model):
nome = models.CharField(max_length=255)
data = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)

class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = 'Menu'

# Python 2
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.nome

# Python 3
def __str__(self):
    return self.nome
```

and a Submenu class:

```
class Submenu(models.Model):
nome = models.CharField(max_length=255)
data = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
menu = models.ForeignKey(Menu, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = 'Submenu'

# Python 2
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.nome

# Python 3
def __str__(self):
    return self.nome
```

Then in admin.py I added:

```
class SubmenuAdmin(admin.StackedInline):
model = Submenu
extra = 0

class MenuAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
list_display = ['__str__']
inlines = [SubmenuAdmin,]

class Meta:
    model = Menu

admin.site.register(Menu, MenuAdmin)
```

Now my goal is to be able to print the various menus in the template with a FOR loop, and under each respective menu the various submenus, as in this photo:

[image: Menu & Submenu]

In views.py I did something like this:

```
def Home(request):
menus = Menu.objects.all().order_by('-data')
submenu_set = Submenu.objects.all().order_by('-data')
context = {
    'menus':menus,
    'submenu_set':submenu_set,
}
return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

Comment: are you mean -  render on admin - object list,  or where?

Comment: I want to display the menu and submenu in index.html, that is to say in templates

Comment: you mean this file - templates/admin/index.html ?

Answer (score 0):

in template you can do:

```
<ul>
    {% for menu in menus %}
        <li>
            {{ menu }} (menu)
            <ul>
                {% for submenu in menu.submenu_set.all %}
                    <li>
                        {{ submenu }} (submenu)
                    </li>
                {% endfor%}
            <ul>
        </li>
    {% endfor%}
</ul>
```

But i think you can do better:

Only one class Menu:

```
class Menu(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    data = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='children' on_delete=models.CASCADE, required=False)
```

And in template:

```
<ul>
    {% for menu in menus %}
        <li>
            {{ menu }} (menu)
            <ul>
                {% for submenu in menu.children.all %}
                    <li>
                        {{ submenu }} (submenu)
                    </li>
                {% endfor%}
            <ul>
        </li>
    {% endfor%}
</ul>
```

Comment: I added my own views.py code. Based on your answer, how should I change it?

Comment: you can add my first example in your template, you should add menus in context

Comment: if I would like to add your second example what should I change?

Comment: Another question. If I want to sort the submenu items by date, how should I do it?

Comment: You can Create in ModelManager method "sorted_by_date". This method should change order of queryset. (return self.order_by('data')). After that in template instead of  menu.children.all you can use menu.children.sorted_by_date